# Call python function with C++ pointers

Tags: c++, boost-python

I want to pass a callable object from Python to C++ and then call it from C++ with arguments for which I have registered `base_`. Example:

```cpp
namespace bpy = boost::python;

bpy::class_<X, X*, boost::noncopyable>("X", bpy::no_init);

bpy::def("f", +[](bpy::object fn) {
  fn(new X());
});
```

Then from python:

```py
from example import f

def fn(x):
  print "x.g() =", x.g()

f(fn)
```

Throws:

> TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: X

I have no issue with callable taking other types of arguments, e.g., `int`, `float` or some other types I have registered, but this one is failing and I don't understand why: why is a by-value conversion required when I'm passing a `X*` and I've specified that the held type for `X` is `X*`.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Full example on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3492d2e846d705c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Argument Handling in Calling Python Functions and Methods](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/python/doc/v2/callbacks.html#argument_handling):

> Arguments are converted to Python according to their type. By default,
>   the arguments a1...aN are copied into new Python objects, but this
>   behavior can be overridden by the use of ptr() and ref():
>
> class X : boost::noncopyable {    ... };
>
> void apply(PyObject* callable, X& x) {    // Invoke callable, passing
>   a Python object which holds a reference to x
>   boost::python::call(callable, boost::ref(x)); }

It seems that even though the pointer type is specified the implementation takes the base non-pointer type. But in this case either `boost::ref` or `bpy::ptr` can be used to fix the problem anyway.

Change:

```
bpy::def("f", +[](bpy::object fn) {
  fn(new X());
});
```

into:

```
bpy::def("f", +[](bpy::object fn) {
    return fn(bpy::ptr(new X()));
});
```

And now it works:

```
$ python test.py 
x.g() = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I found right after posting the question. Problem is that in my use case, those are templated stuffs, so I would have to apply `bpy::ptr` (or `boost::ref`) depending on the argument, but not all pointer/ref arguments should be wrapped, which makes quite a mess in the end... I wonder the reasoning behind this weird behavior since for python functions defined with `bpy::def` or `bpy::class_::def`, the argument is correctly wrap automatically, and same when calling `get_override` from wrappers.